# Is there a connection between limit point of a subset of a metric space and the limit of a function?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, metric-spaces, definition

Is there a connection between limit point of a subset of a metric space and the limit of a function, or limit of a sequence?

I am not sure but I don't think there is because there can be more than one limit point of a subset of a metric space whereas the limit of a function is unique.

Is there a connection between these two terms that I am missing?

Comment: In addition to Henry's answer, when we precisely define the expression $\lim_{x\to a} f(x)=L$ for a real-valued function defined on some $D\subset \mathbb{R}$, we mean that $a$ is a limit point of $D$. So we are looking at the value of the function $f(x)$ as it approaches a limit point of the domain. This ensures $f(x)$ is defined "near" $a$, but not necessarily at $a$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $(X,d)$ is a metric space and $S \subseteq X$. Then $x$ is a limit point of $S$ if and only if there exists a sequence $(x_j)_{j=0}^\infty$ in $S$ such that $x_j \to x$.

Comment: Since we can have many different sequences for $S$, $S$ can have many different limit points, correct?

Comment: @AlJebr Yes. Each limit point can be treated as a limit.

Answer (score 1):

The most direct connection would probably be "Suppose that a sequence $(x_n)$ is in a metric space $X$ and $x_n\to x$, then $x$ is the limit point of $S=\{x_n|n\in \Bbb N\}$ iff $S$ is an infinite set."

This means that the *limit* of a sequence is also the *only limit point* of the range of the sequence whenever the sequence is not eventually constant.